# mysql group by with having removes results from sum over

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I have a query that is grouping items, selecting the number of items in a group, and also what percentage that group is of all of the items that were not filtered out in the where clause

I would like to remove any groups that have two or fewer items in them in order to have fewer results that are a small fraction of the entire dataset.

here is my (simplified) query:

```
select count(i.itemId) as itemCount,
       concat(format(100 * count(i.itemId) / sum(count(i.itemId)) over (), 2), '%') as totalPercentage
from thing t
join item i on t.thingId = i.thingId
where t.createdDate > startdate and t.createdDate < enddate
group by t.thingId
order by count(i.itemId) desc, t.thingId desc;
```

I thought that I should just add a having clause like this:

```
...
group by t.thingId
having count(i.itemId) > 2
order by count(i.itemId) desc, t.thingId desc;
```

would solve the problem, but when I do that the results show a total percentage that is now inaccurate, because the `sum(count(i.itemId)) over ()` is now ignoring the groups that have 2 or fewer items in them.

I know that it is possible to do this by making this query an inner query and then filtering in a select that is outside this query, but I would prefer not to do that, given that on my team we try to avoid inner queries unless they are necessary.

I also know that it is possible to make a temp table, and filter this by selecting from that temp table, but I don't even want to go into that, because it seems ugly.

TLDR: Is it possible to filter out groups from the result of a select, but have them still included in a `sum() over ()` clause without any shenanigans?

Comment: Any filtering removes rows from the result set, so calculation have no access to them. Analytic functions are calculated at the final steps of query execution (before `select` list expression evaluation and `order by`), so to filter out some rows you have to put your calculation into subquery and apply filter in outer query

Comment: Avoiding "inner queries" (sub-queries/inline-views) demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of SQL. You're incorrectly treating it as an imperative language, but it's declarative; the syntax allows you to express a problem, then the DBMS generates a plan to solve it. Just because something is in a sub-query does Not mean the DBMS will execute it blindly. Predicate pushdown, macro like expansion, and other methods, mean that the plan generated is not that naive. For example `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM X) AS Y WHERE foo='bar'` yields the exact same plan as `SELECT * FROM X WHERE foo='bar'`

Answer (score 2):

Calculate first the percentage and use that as subquery and then filter later, as any filtering will remove rows that you need

you ned up with

```
SELECT
    itemCount,totalPercentage
FROM
    (select 
        t.thingId,
        count(i.itemId) as itemCount,
        concat(format(100 * count(i.itemId) / sum(count(i.itemId)) over (), 2), '%') as totalPercentage
    from thing t
    join item i on t.thingId = i.thingId
    where t.createdDate > startdate and t.createdDate < enddate
    group by t.thingId) t1
WHERE intemCount = 2
order by itemCount desc, thingId desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it's not possible to compute percentages in SQL without the help of a subquery. To generate percentages you need a total to divide by and that takes a separate aggregating query.

I hope your team's policy about subqueries actually says "avoid [dependent a/k/a correlated subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) whenever possible."  Those are the ones that can hammer performance.   Avoiding all subqueries as a matter of policy? That's sort of like avoiding subroutines in programming -- it prohibits the use of a major language feature.

Comment: This is factually inaccurate. Windowed/analytic functions allow exactly this without sub-queries. The problem the op is facing is that they are trying to filter And apply an analytic function in the same scope, and finding that the order of the operations causes the filter to be applied first. As for avoiding correlated sub-queries as a general principle, that's faulty too. With correct formulation and indexing there is nothing wrong with them. This answer is littered with fallacies.

Answer (score 0):

you can try case statements so that it gives null percentage then later filter out null values in next stage be it sql or some front end code.

```
...
case when count(i.itemId) > 2 
then concat(format(100 * count(i.itemId) / sum(count(i.itemId)) over (), 2), '%') end as 
totalPercentage
...
```

this might just increase computation time, or just an outer query to filter it out can be used as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: The op wants to exclude rows, this doesn't exclude rows.  As for excluding them later, "exclude rows with 1's or 2's" would work just as well, making replacing them with NULLs completely redundant.

Comment: @MatBailie they can replace with any values, yes there can be much better ways then null.